# Parts/Step not fitting ( technic / gear not aligning)

Tags: technic, gears

[image]working on Lego Technic; Recovery truck.
Reached Step 27(book 1)....fixing the rope spool. and found that the white gear wheel is not fitting in. i.e., i have the white gear fixed on the shaft with the spool, but when i try to fit it on the frame, it does not fit in, if i force it in, it goes on a angle. 
have relooked at the previous steps and can't see any part missed out or put in wrongly.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?
isn't the white gear wheel supposed to align with the small black gear wheel?

Comment: Are you able to post an image of the assembly and perhaps an image of the instruction page?

Comment: i Have added a image of the instruction page on the main post. the orange arrows show the parts which are not aligning. we had disassmebled the assembly to few steps back. will assemble back and send a images.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. I had a part wrongly fitted. 
both parts look similar ( black gear wheel)...one(part#6012451) is smaller that other(part #4177431).
back on track now. .. :-)

Comment: Cheers for letting us know you solved it :)